# Firefox using old dataset for D3 visualisation

Tags: html, json, firefox, browser, local-storage

I have a web app which consists of a frontend HTML page where the user enters some search parameters, a PHP processing file which takes the search parameters and uses an online Web API to retrieve relevant data and then passes it to another HTML file, where the data is displayed in a dynamic bar chart with D3.  The PHP process creates a JSON file, `data.json`, which is imported via `$.getJSON` in the second HTML page.

This works fine in Chrome and IE but not in Firefox.  If I clear the browser history and run a search, then everything works fine.  Any subsequent searches I do do not show the new data, but the data from that original search after the history deletion, even though the `data.json` file is updating correctly.

So this makes me think that Firefox is for some reason storing the initial `data.json` data somehow and using that data each time the page is called.

I haven't included any code because it seems more about the semantics of Firefox than a problem with the code.  It did seem to start doing this after I styled the site with Bootstrap/Bootswatch but I don't see why that would have any effect.

Any ideas why this is happening, please?!

Comment: Why are you sending the data to a static file in the first place? You should just echo the contents from your PHP script. If you want to prevent caching you can use a header but I consider that a workaround. Another workaround would be to add ?somerandomvalue to the end of the URL for data.json

Comment: I'm new to web development and from doing research into how to get the data from the PHP script to the HTML, that was what I came up with.  Not sure how to echo the contents of the PHP script but I'll look into it if that works better.